# I've been using exec 5> debug_output.txt / BASH_XTRACEFD="5" to debug scripts but it literally stopped working overnight

Tags: bash, ubuntu-14.04

I'm new to scripting so I've been using:

```
exec 5> debug_output.txt
BASH_XTRACEFD="5"
```

to send the output of a script to debug_output.txt.  This was allowing me to compare the output of the script with what the script was doing which I find to be very helpful.  I was testing with this setup last night and it was working fine.  I came in this morning and now it doesn't work.  I'm using the exact same script in the exact same terminal.  The script will run and the debug_output.txt file is created but it is empty.  I tried deleting debug_output.txt and the myscript1.sh and recreating it, with no change.  Rebooting didn't work either.  Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 5> debug_output.txt
BASH_XTRACEFD="5"
PS4='$LINENO: '

var1=blah
var2=foo

echo Currently in $0
echo
echo $0 :: var1 : $var1, var2 : $var2

export var1
echo
echo Entering myscript2.sh
./myscript2.sh
echo
echo Back in $0
echo $0 :: var1 : $var1, var2 : $var2
echo
```

Here is the output:

```
(^)#(^)#(^)#(^)bminter@ubuntu:~/bashscripttutorial$ ./myscript1.sh 
Currently in ./myscript1.sh

./myscript1.sh :: var1 : blah, var2 : foo

Entering myscript2.sh
Currently in ./myscript2.sh

./myscript2.sh :: var1 : blah, var2 :

Back in ./myscript1.sh
./myscript1.sh :: var1 : blah, var2 : foo

(^)#(^)#(^)#(^)bminter@ubuntu:~/bashscripttutorial$
```

Here are the contents after the script runs:

```
(^)#(^)#(^)#(^)bminter@ubuntu:~/bashscripttutorial$ ls
debug_output.txt  foo  myscript1.sh  myscript1.sh~  myscript2.sh  myscript2.sh~
(^)#(^)#(^)#(^)bminter@ubuntu:~/bashscripttutorial$ cat debug_output.txt 
(^)#(^)#(^)#(^)bminter@ubuntu:~/bashscripttutorial$ 
(^)#(^)#(^)#(^)bminter@ubuntu:~/bashscripttutorial$
```

I wish I had the contents of the debug_output.txt file when it worked last night but I lost that when I rebooted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from [bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html)

> BASH_XTRACEFD
>
> If set to an integer corresponding to a valid file descriptor, Bash will write the trace output generated when ‘set -x’ is enabled to that file descriptor. This allows tracing output to be separated from diagnostic and error messages. The file descriptor is closed when BASH_XTRACEFD is unset or assigned a new value. Unsetting BASH_XTRACEFD or assigning it the empty string causes the trace output to be sent to the standard error. Note that setting BASH_XTRACEFD to 2 (the standard error file descriptor) and then unsetting it will result in the standard error being closed.

So `set -x` is missing in script provided.

Or `bash -x` or `set -o errtrace`

Comment: That did it.  I added `set -x` just below 'BASH_XTRACEFD="5"`.  I still don't understand why it worked last night without it.  Thanks